# Is it possible to create web application (web site) using ionic?

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, ionic-framework, mobile-application

is it possible to create web application using ionic or is it only for mobile ? what is the difference between Angular and Ionic

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do it. However, it's probably not advisable. Ionic just provides a bunch of directives for you to use. You can use that in conjunction with something like Cordova/Phonegap to package that up for a mobile release. Otherwise, you could just take the web parts of the project (i.e. all your html/js/css/assets) and point a web server to them and *presto* - you can access your ionic page with a browser.

However...

You probably don't want to do this for a few reasons.

1. Ionic wasn't written to target desktop pages
2. Ionic doesn't really provide anything for desktop pages that A. doesn't already exist in Angular or B. someone hasn't properly written for desktop solutions

My suggestion here is to just use plain Angular or another framework such as React/Vue.

To answer the last part of your question: Angular is the framework that Ionic provides bindings (and some assets such as icons) for. Those bindings happen to be optimised/targetted towards mobile devices.

Hopefully that helps out a bit.